# AutoHotKey Array

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

```
;MouseGetPos, X, Y
;msgbox %x%, %y%
;MouseClick, left, 113, 376
MyArray := {}
MyArray.insert("cat")
CoordMode,Mouse,Screen
F1::    
    msgbox % MyArray
    while (%var% != "false"){
        MouseGetPos, X, Y
        msgbox %x%, %y%
        MyArray.insert(x, y)
        msgbox %MyArray%

    }
F2::
    Pause
F3::
    Reload
F4::
    ExitApp
F5::
    var:="false"
    Run C:\Windows\Notepad.exe "C:\Users\YUKI\Desktop\Test.txt"
    sleep 2000
    send {Enter}
    sleep 2000
    send {Enter}
    FileAppend, %L%
    sleep 4000
    send {Enter}
    send {alt}
    send {a}
    send {o}
    send {Enter}
```

I want to insert a getMousePosition into a list, I think I'm initializing the array incorrectly, or inserting the x and y variables incorrectly

Comment: When you print msgbox, print an empty list || 0, you should at least print a list containing 0 & "cat"

Answer (score 0):

Array.Insert() is for indexed arrays (`MyArray := []`) but you have declared an associative array (`MyArray := {}`).
Associative arrays are for key/value pairs - eg `MyArray.Cat := 1`
Indexed arrays have automatic keys of increasing numbers - eg `MyArray[1] := "Blah"`.
In general, with an indexed array, you would add new items to the end with `MyArray.push("Blah")` rather than using `.insert()` to insert at a specific point.
To store previous positions and such you probably want an indexed array, so change `MyArray := {}` to `MyArray := []` and change `MyArray.insert(x, y)` to  `MyArray.push({x: x, y: y})`
Note here that I am inserting an associative array holding x and y key/value pairs to the indexed array.
To access individual coordinates, it would be `MyArray[5].x` or `MyArray[5].y`
`MyArray.Length()` will tell you how many items there are in the array.

See the docs [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm) for more info.